# Combining proxy_pass and auth_basic leads to infinite loading

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a little problem with `proxy_pass` and `auth_basic` combining in the same location.
I use nginx as reverse-proxy for Bluemap (https://bluemap.bluecolored.de/) I and want to enable http authentification.

My current configuration:

```
location /map/ {
    
        auth_basic "Restricted Area";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/auth/htpasswd;
    
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://172.18.0.1:8100/;

}
```

But with `auth_basic` I always getting infinite loading loop for the `<domain>/map` page.

- `htpasswd` file exist.
- It seems working if I use `auth_basic` without `proxy_pass`.
- Also there are no errors in /var/log/nginx/error.log.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google Chrome just has weird behaviour and doesn't show authentication popup until it's been restarted.